# Cant access GCP Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I have GCP cloud compute free tier *(f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory))*. A few weeks ago I can access it but why now I can not access it. I run command `ssh root@IP` but return:

```
ssh: connect to host IP port 22: Operation timed out
```

I tried access SSH to the platform console but return:
[image]

I tried stop and start the instance but still can't be access.

I only can connect without identify-aware proxy.

How can I access my compute from my local?

I never turn on firewall

```
dyaskur@instance-3:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need to apply [GCP firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to allow ingress connection on SSH port of that instance on the VPC network.

By default there is default ingress rule for allowing ssh in GCP. You can [create](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules)  firewall rules in GCP manually as well.

If your GCP VM [instacne does not have external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances), make sure you are connected using either [VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#vpn), [bastion host](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#bastion_host) or [Identity-Aware Proxy(IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#cloud_iap) for TCP forwarding.

You may need to allow ingress traffic from the [IP range 35.235.240.0/20](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule)  in GCP firewall if you are using IAP to connect the instance. This IP range is used by IAP for TCP forwarding.