# Cannot SSH to Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcp

I have a similar problem as outlined here: [Cant access GCP Compute Engine](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039374/cant-access-gcp-compute-engine)

Yesterday I lost access to my GCP server.  I thought Google was having issues but almost 40 hrs later I'm thinking their issues would be resolved by now.

I've tried:

- From home & work and both access attempts fail (SSH in-browser fails & Putty).
- Both Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed & without IAP failed

I have `default-allow-ssh` = 0.0.0.0/0 allow from anywhere

Recent(past 6 montsh) Firewall changes?: No

Answer (score 0):

I decided to stop and start the instance.  This resolved the problem and I can click "ssh" and ssh in-browser and from putty as expected now.  Note: Unfortunately this results in a new IP address so beware!

Comment: That means you have assigned an ephemeral IP address. You can switch that IP address to static. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address